# How can send Task Email Reminders for Users before end deadline task

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, phpmailer

Hi i need to send a reminder mail use mailtrap for each user has a task that still have open status before one day from deadline

using mail

here tasks table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('project_id')->constrained();
            $table->date('deadline');
            $table->string('status')->default('open');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: please provide further information, it is a wide question :) At a high level cron jobs can do the work and consider using supervisor, But from which source ? Database, redis,etc etc etc.

Comment: It's unclear where you're stuck. Please be more specific about the actual problem you're facing.

Comment: Where's the code to check for the users that need to reminded? Or the code that sends a mail?

Comment: please check the portential solution and accept it if it makes sense down below hope it helps you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful.
First configure the email section on the .env file the parameters can be obtained directly from mailtrap under SMTP settings.
You can leave the QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync , later on i would suggest to use redis or sqs.
And leverage the queue component with information from here,

[Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues)

1- Create a model Reminder: php artisan make:model Reminder

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reminder extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function Task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }

    public function getStatusAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

2- Define a command: php artisan make:command SendReminderEmails

Add the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\User;
use App\Models\Reminder;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Mail\ReminderEmailDigest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendReminderEmails extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'reminder:emails';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Get all reminders for today
        $reminders = Reminder::query()
            ->with(['task'])
            ->where('deadline', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', now())))
            ->where('status', 'open')
            ->orderByDesc('user_id')
            ->get();

        // group all reminders by user
        $data = [];
        foreach ($reminders as $reminder) {
            $data[$reminder->user_id][] = $reminder->toArray();
        }

        foreach ($data as $userId => $reminders) {
            $this->sendEmailToUser($userId, $reminders);
        }
    }

    private function sendEmailToUser($userId, $reminders)
    {
        $user = User::find($userId);

        Mail::to($user)->send(new ReminderEmailDigest($reminders));
    }
}
```

3- Create two files /resources/views/emails/reminder-digest.blade.php and /app/Mail/ReminderEmailDigest.php

Add to /app/Mail/ReminderEmailDigest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ReminderEmailDigest extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $reminders;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($reminders)
    {
        $this->reminders = $reminders;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.reminder-digest')
            ->with('reminders', $this->reminders);
    }
}
```

4- Add to /resources/views/emails/reminder-digest.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
# You have some reminders to follow up. Below are their details:

@component('mail::table')
|Reminder|Task title|Task description|
|:-------|:--------|:----|
@foreach($reminders as $reminder)
|{{$reminder['reminder']}}|{{$reminder['task']['title']}}|{{$reminder['task']['description']}}
@endforeach
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

5-Add to /app/Console/Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use App\Console\Commands\SendReminderEmails;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        SendReminderEmails::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

6- while running the app run: php artisan queue:listen